# deployment of Linux program on Windows that needs audio recording

Tags: linux, docker, windows-subsystem-for-linux, microphone, pulseaudio

I've a python code with packages that only support Linux, and it requires audio recording as well. The code is expected to run on Windows for deployment.

I've tried 2 solutions for that:

1- Linux docker container, the container works on Windows without any problem, but it couldn't record audio (it couldn't see the microphone and it was producing alsa errors). I tried many solutions that include PulseAudio, but none could solve the problem.

2- WSL/WSL2, the code works and it didn't show any error. I can play audio in WSL and hear it from my headphones, but I couldn't record anything from my microphone. I tried many solutions as well but none works for me (solutions with PulseAudio).

Do you have any suggestions or any solutions for the problems above that you have tested yourself?

Thank you,

Answer (score 1):

I resolved the problem...

1- For PULSE_SERVER, export the ip of your computer not 127.0.0.1.

2- Set the variable record to 1 instead of 0 in module-waveout.

Comment: Hi @lamya1, could you please provide more details on your setup to use microphone from inside the Docker container? I'm also using PulseAudio, $PULSE_SERVER also assigned to my computer's IP and 'record' assigned to 1. With all the such conditions, I tried to mount the /dev/snd and /dev/bus/usb devices to my container but it doesn't work.